# Big-O Space requirement for multiplication

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o, space-complexity

Stack Overflow.  I see some great resources on time complexity here, but so far I haven't been able to answer to this space complexity question using them.  So:

If I am multiplying the first n primes together, what *space* would be required to store the answer?  For example, multiplying the first thousand primes together and storing the resulting number (an integer, albeit a large one).  Would it require n-squared or log(n) space?

Thanks so much!

Comment: My initial thoughts are that the Big-O space requirement is probably the same as that for n! - but that's just a feeling...

Answer (score 1):

The [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) tells us that the *n*th prime is approximately *n* ln *n*, so the product of the first *n* primes is approximately

> Π<sub>*i* ≤ *n*</sub>(*i* ln *i*) = *n*! O((log *n*)<sup>*n*</sup>) = O((*n* log *n*)<sup>*n*</sup>)

And to represent this number you'd need space that's the logarithm of that, i.e.

> O(*n* (log *n* + log log *n*)).

(Note that this is asymptotically bigger than the space needed to store *n*!, which is just O(*n* log *n*).)

Answer (score 0):

Just taking the last part of your question. If you have a list of the first n primes, the # of digits in the final multiplication will be log(n^n) which is just n log n. Since the algorithm would just be to multiply each one with a single accumulator, i would say the total space requirement would be the final expected # of digits, which is: n log(n)

Comment: Why would the number of digits in the final multiplication be log(n^n)?  I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm just not seeing that crucial step...!

Comment: I reckon there are more than O(n log n) digits in the product of the first n primes. See my answer.